# Choosing between $n$ things using dice?

Tags: probability, algorithms, dice

For which $n$ is there a finite algorithm to choose between $n$ things with the same probability using a die?

For example, we can choose between 2 things, 3 things, 4 things, 6 things, and 8 things, but it seems we cannot choose between 7 things with a finite algorithm.

Comment: What do you call *a finite algorithm* exactly?

Comment: @Did Good question. One interpretation is an algorithm based on a predefined number of dice rolls. Another would allow a random number of dice rolls, but with the number of rolls having a finite expectation. With this definition, any $n$ is possible.

Comment: If you want _pessimistic_ finite time, then (as Ross Millikan pointed out) $\frac{1}{n}$ has to be a fraction that terminates in base $6$ (i.e. $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{p}{6^q}$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$). If you want _expected_ finite time, then any finite $n$ is good.

Comment: by finite algorithm, I mean a finite number of throws. a finite series of actions (without loops used in programming) which lead to a choice. Another similar example is: There is not a finite process which divides any angle to three equal ones.

Comment: Your analogy with trisection is flawed: You *can* use dice to chose exactly uniformly between $n$ outcomes in a finite number of throws, but you can't determine that finite number before you start. There is no analogue for this statement in the trisection case: There, you *never* achieve an exact trisection.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: the difference, is the difference between probabilities. one has nonzero probability and the other zero probabilty. given an angle. choose 2 points. Then draw from the points to vertex. if it does not trisect, choose another two points. this is an infinite alogrithm. but if you win, you have done a finite number of actions. but the probability is zero.

Comment: If you say so. But I think the difference between zero probability and nonzero probability is quite fundamental. In this case, it is the difference between finite expectation on one hand and zero probability even after infinitely many attempts on the other!

Comment: *by finite algorithm, I mean a finite number of throws. a finite series of actions(without loops used in programming) which lead to a choice*... Unfortunately this does not really answer my question.

Comment: @Di d: You are given 7 things and you have to choose between them. How many dice do you need so that you can choose between the 7 things uniformly with one throw (of m dice simultaneously).

Comment: @CuteKrait You can never do it exactly. You can, however, get close enough for all practical purposes, as an engineer would say.

Comment: If you throw, say, 20 dice, the probability that the minuscule unevenness affects the results is 1 in 3,000 trillion.

Comment: @JoeZeng: I'm not talking about probability. For 7 choice there are not any m dice which can give a certain answer in one throw. Just wanted to explain what is a finite alogrithm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a six sided die you can choose between any number of options of the form $2^p3^q$ with a finite process, but no others.  The number of possible throws is always $6^k$ and so you need a fraction that terminates in base $6$, which means the denominator has to have factors only of $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Care to explain why you can't select between others?

Comment: @vonbrand:  the same reason you can't select out of $5$.  After $k$ rolls you will have $6^k$ possibilities, which you can't split evenly among the choices.  You can use $1$ through $5$ to make choices and reroll the $6$ if you want, but that *might* go on forever.  That is why the number of choices has to divide evenly into $6^k$ for some $k$.  Primes other than $2$ and $3$ never do.

Answer (score 1):

Given $n$ events, throw $k = \lceil \log_6 n \rceil$ dice, to generate a number from $1$ to $6^k$ in base 6. If the number thrown is greater than $n$, keep throwing until you get a number that's less than $n$.

While this will never be guaranteed to terminate in a specified number of throws, the more you throw, the greater the probability that one of the events *will* be one you can use, and the probability that this process does go on forever vanishes to zero.

If you require exact probabilities on a single throw, then Ross' solution is the best you can get, as your sample space is always going to be a power of 6 and the only way to divide that sample space up among events equally is to use a number of events that is a factor of a power of 6.

Comment: >If the number thrown (ie k) is greater than n (ie n < k), keep throwing (ie add to k) until you get a number that's less than n (ie k<n). ...?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I'm saying. I mean something along the lines of: Given 28 events, throw two dice, one white and one black, using the white as the "sixes" digit. Suppose the white die came up 5 and the black die came up 5. This means you rolled 29, which is too high (greater than 28), so you roll again.